# JQuery click() event fires twice when called by live()

Tags: jquery

http://pastebin.com/1MGTtzij here is my full html document, and below is the short version:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDiv").append($("<input />", {
                            type : "button",
                            id : "myButton1",
                            value : "Click me first!"
                        }));
        $("#myButton1").live("click", function () {
            var a = 1;
            $("#myButton2").click(function () {
                alert(a);
            });
        });
    });
```

with the HTML code:

```
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <input type="button" id="myButton2" value="Click me!" />
```

After the page stoped load and fully show, you will see 2 button **Click me first!** and **Click me!**, do after me:

1. click **Click me first!** - nothing happen - OK
2. click **Click me!** - alert 1 - OK
3. click **Click me first!** - nothing happen - OK
4. click **Click me!** - alert 1 - alert 1 ?????????????
   So I recognized that if I click on **Click me first!** N times, I will get (N + 1) alerts. How can I fix that??

Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the click handler is called on button 1, you are adding a new click handler on button 2. That is why its increasing.

```
$("#myButton1").live("click", function () {
    var a = 1;
    // Don't add a new handler here. Move this outside of the `live` call
    $("#myButton2").click(function () {
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

I've moved the `variable` to be accessible by the click handlers of both buttons, and moved the click handler setup outside. See a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BQuUM/).

Comment: As an aside: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7+. You should switch to using `.on()` if your jQuery version is 1.7 or higher. Even if it's not, `.delegate()` has long been considered a superior alternative to the much-despised (yet heavily-used!!!) `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click myButton1, you're adding a new .click handler to myButton2.

If you really want to do it this way, you can do: `$("#myButton2").unbind('click');` before that `$("#myButton2").click` call.

Answer (score -1):

It is because every time you `click` on `click me first!` button a click handler will be attached to `Click me` button and it keep on adding. Move the code to attach click event handler outside. Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDiv").append($("<input />", {
                            type : "button",
                            id : "myButton1",
                            value : "Click me first!"
                        }));
        $("#myButton1").live("click", function () {
            var a = 1;

        });
        $("#myButton2").click(function () {
                alert(a);
        });
    });
```